# ERRO Array to string conversion on line 28

Tags: php, array

Estava vendo um tutorial e no vídeo do instrutor que foi postado não dava esse erro, e agora está dando comigo:

> Array to string conversion on line 28

Já procurei uma solução e nos vídeos falavam para eu colocar um `echo`, mas já coloquei e não funcionou.

```
private function GetLista(){
        $i = 1;
        while($lista = $this->ListarDados()):
        $this->itens[$i] = array(
            'cate_id' => $lista['cate_id'],
            'cate_nome' => $lista['cate_nome'],
            'cate_slug' => $lista['cate_slug'],
            'cate_link' => Rotas::pag_Produtos(). '/' .$lista['cate_id'] . '/' . ['cate_slug']
        );

        $i++;
        endwhile;
    }
```

Comment: Fala aí, Still! Nessa pergunta eu editei pra arrumar. Para as suas próximas, leia [formatação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Outra coisa: o erro ocorre na linha 28. Mas no seu código postado não tem 28 linhas... Que tal apontar, nesse código, qual é a linha 28? ;D

Comment: Olá, desculpe e que eu não sabia da formatação, mas nos próximos posts eu vou colocar :p

Comment: Dando uma olhada superficial, achei um erro aqui: `'cate_link' => Rotas::pag_Produtos(). '/' .$lista['cate_id'] . '/' . ['cate_slug']
`. Essa parte: `['cate_slug']` deveria ser `$lista['cate_slug']`, não?! :)

Comment: Olá, obrigado esse era o erro mesmo, infelizmente foi um erro meu na hora de digitar, obrigado por me ajudar, tem alguma parte de postagem para iniciantes? Ou posso publicar no geral mesmo?

Comment: O ideal é vc fazer o [tour] e dar uma breve lida na [central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help). Se já achou o problema, vou formular uma resposta e damos essa por encerrada. =)

Comment: Olá Still. Acredito que a resposta do @LipESprY-defolga- está correta. Se ela solucionou o problema, você é o único capaz de aprova-la. Veja mais aqui > https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/15361

Answer (score 1):

Repare nessa linha:

```
'cate_link' => Rotas::pag_Produtos(). '/' .$lista['cate_id'] . '/' . ['cate_slug']
```

Faltou declarar a *array* aqui: `['cate_slug']`... Veja como fica:

```
'cate_link' => Rotas::pag_Produtos(). '/' .$lista['cate_id'] . '/' . $lista['cate_slug']
```

Comment: Tinha acabado de postar ... ^^

Comment: Só fiz uma triagem antes, via comentário. ;D

Comment: kkkk Ta certo! =)